# Cookie Path in CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option

Tags: cookies

I have a PHP cURL script to login a website and post data...

Everything is fine.... i only want to give a path to cookie files to a folder in my domain where their are many cookie files...

My script----

http://pastebin.com/45bRENLN

The modification i want....

http://pastebin.com/KDtDYEXV

This doesnt work... Y??
Can anyone help me out....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you were looking for. The only differences in both documents you wrote were the /g/ in the folder you wanted to save cookies at.

In order to save cookies in the same folder and read them from it you may use the following code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__). '/cookie.txt'); //read cookies from here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt'); //save cookies here
```

Hope it helps.